# How to read date from text file, assign it to date and remove duplicate date in C# Linq

Tags: c#, linq, date, asp.net-mvc-5

How can I approach this exercise? I don't know how to read text files using LINQ. Does anyone have an idea on how I can approach this?

**input.txt**

```
2013/05/28 06:44:28 AM
2013/04/12 02:27:00 AM
2013/04/08 09:37:00 PM
2013/04/16 11:23:00 AM
2013/04/14 09:47:00 PM
2013/04/05 07:29:00 PM
2013/03/29 03:12:00 PM
2013/04/06 07:43:00 AM
2013/04/16 01:08:00 AM
```

The text file contains a list of times. I want to read in this text file and order these times in ASCENDING order and remove duplicate times.
Then display these times on a page in an MVC solution as explained below.

The date times must be grouped by day AND week and empty weeks or days must be displayed as well. The output must look as follows (This just an example):

**Week : Sunday April 28 to Saturday May 4**

Sun April 28

Mon April 29
2013/04/29 03:12:00 AM

Tue April 30
2013/04/30 01:16:00 PM
2013/04/30 05:01:00 PM

Wed May 1
2013/05/01 06:33:00 AM

Thu May 2

Fri May 3

Sat May 4

Answer (score 3):

First you need to define the **CultureInfo** you are going to be using for all text conversions. The ones in you example look like US, so lets use that one.

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-us");
```

Then you need to parse those lines of text as DateTimes so you can work with them. **Distinct** will make sure there are no duplicates and **OrderBy** will sort the result with the default DateTime comparison (ascending)

```
//Use full path instead of "input.txt"
IEnumerable<DateTime> datesInFile = File.ReadAllLines(@"input.txt")
    .Select(s => DateTime.Parse(s, culture))
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(d => d);
```

The days of a week can be enumerated by iterating 7 days starting with a specified date.

```
//This date should probably come from somewhere else
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2013, 04, 08);
IEnumerable<DateTime> datesInWeek = Enumerable.Range(0, 6)
    .Select(d => startDate.Date.AddDays(d));
```

Since you need all timestamps per day, you need to group them by date. **ToDictionary** will expect to lambdas: The first will be the **key** (the date) and the second the **value** (list of timestamps with that day).

```
Dictionary<DateTime, IEnumerable<DateTime>> result = datesInWeek
    .ToDictionary(
        d => d, 
        d => datesInFile.Where(dif => d.Date == dif.Date));
```

Lastly you can take your results and aggregate them (in the specified culture and format of course)

```
string outputText = result.Aggregate("", 
    (current, pair) => current + 
    pair.Key.ToString("ddd MMM d", culture) + 
    Environment.NewLine + 
    String.Join(Environment.NewLine, pair.Value.Select(
        d => d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", culture))) + 
    Environment.NewLine);
```

Compact Version:

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-us");

IEnumerable<DateTime> datesInFile = File
    .ReadAllLines(@"C:\Temp\input.txt")
    .Select(s => DateTime.Parse(s, culture))
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(d => d);

string outputText = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 6)
    .Select(d => new DateTime(2013,04,08).Date.AddDays(d))
    .ToDictionary(d => d, d => datesInFile.Where(dif => d.Date == dif.Date))
    .Aggregate("", (current, pair) => current + pair.Key.ToString("ddd MMM d", culture) + Environment.NewLine + 
        String.Join(Environment.NewLine, pair.Value.Select(d => d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", culture))) + 
        Environment.NewLine);
```